# Method is not abstract and does not override method in Interface error

Tags: java, interface, overriding

I'm getting the following error when trying to compile my code:

> `MyClass` is not abstract and does not override abstract method `actionPerformed(ActionEvent)` in `ActionListener`

I have already looked around at other posts and solutions to do with this error but I cant  fix it.

Here is my code:

```
package NinjaChefGame;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;


public class Animation extends JPanel implements  ActionListener {
    Timer    tm = new Timer (5,this);
    int x = 0, velx = 2;

    public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor  (Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(x,30,50,30);
        tm.start();
    }

    public  void actionPerfomed(ActionEvent e) {
        x = x + velx;
        repaint();
    }

}
```

Comment: The error mentions MyClass and the code you posted ist Class Animation. Maybe thats the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an `r` missing

```
public  void actionPerfomed(ActionEvent e) 
                       ^^^
public  void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
```